# Do I need to redownload the Aeon blockchain for the rebased software?

Tags: blockchain, aeon

I have a legacy v0.9.14.0 `aeond` running, fully synchronized. When I install the rebased software, will I need to redownload the Aeon blockchain from scratch, or can I convert the existing blockchain folder to LMDB format directly?

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way to convert the existing blockchain to LMDB format. Technically, you have to re-download. However, since you already have that legacy blockchain, there's a faster way by using that as the exclusive source for your synchronization.

As a first step, relocate the blockchain directory and start up the legacy aeond daemon using the `--data-dir` parameter:

```
mv ${HOME}/.aeon ${HOME}/.aeon-legacy
${PATH_TO_LEGACY}/aeond --data-dir ${HOME}/.aeon-legacy
```

Next, start up the rebased `aeond` daemon using the **`--add-exclusive-node`** parameter and – temporarily – different TCP ports, e.g.:

```
${PATH_TO_REBASE}/aeond --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1 \
    --p2p-bind-port 11190 --rpc-bind-port 11191
```

Once the blockchain is fully synchronized, you should see the message `SYNCHRONIZED OK`. After that, you can stop the legacy `aeond` daemon with the `exit` command, and restart the rebased `aeond` daemon without the extra parameters.

> **Note:** Optionally, you can remove the legacy blockchain directory `${HOME}/.aeon-legacy` if you don't intend to start that up anymore.